# Web View HTML in Android

Tags: android

I'm using `Web View` in my app. I want to pass a value to HTML. For example, I'm making an online payment system; I want to pass a variable that holds the amount to the HTML that will display in my web view.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean MapView or WebView? you mention both!

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain variables in JavaScript and pass it to your WebView after a page is loaded in it. 
Use it as follows:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:var a=(%s);",data);
```